# Qt Quick 2 Qml: Place text exactly in center of circle

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to place a text exactly in the center of a circle in Qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 20
    height: 20
    radius: width/2
    color: "red"
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

    Label { // or Text
        anchors.centerIn: parent // or anchors.fill: parent
        text: "A"
        color: "white"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }

    //EDIT: For testing different locations:
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent        
        drag.target: rect
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the text is slightly off from the center (shifted to the left and bottom). I tested different sizes and characters but all show the same problem. Is there a better way to place the text exactly in the center?

**[EDIT]**: The font offset seems to be related to the position on the screen (but I could not determine what causes it - it happens both with odd and even x coordinates). In other words: when you drag around the circle then the centered character slightly moves around.

Regards,

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not observed the problem, you could place an image where you can observe the problem.

Comment: Tried your code. The offset is only noticeable if the circle is very small. I believe the offset you are seeing is due to the natural character spacing of the font you are using. You could try looking for a more symmetrical font. 

See: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly

Comment: You can try to use `anchors.margin` to correct for the offset, but in that case you should definitely specify your font-family.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have edited the question because it seems that the problem is related to the position on the screen (looks like a rounding or float/int error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put an item, say Item A, in the exact center of another item , you should turn off A's `anchors.alignWhenCentered` (which is true by default in order to make the item painted crisply).

Comment: This seems to fix the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way, not very elegant but it works...

```
Text {
    y: -4
    text: "A"
    color: "white"
    font.pixelSize: 20
    anchors.horizontalCenter: rect.horizontalCenter
}
```